# How to Implement PSO to SVM?

Tags: python, svm, particle-swarm

I am doing my project using SVM classification for sentiment analysis. can I implement Particle Swarm Optimization into my project? and how xD

here some code on my project using jupyter

```
Train_X, Test_X, Train_Y, Test_Y = model_selection.train_test_split(df['Tweet'],df['HS'],test_size=0.2)
Encoder = LabelEncoder()
Train_Y = Encoder.fit_transform(Train_Y)
Test_Y = Encoder.fit_transform(Test_Y)

Tfidf_vect = TfidfVectorizer()
Tfidf_vect.fit(df['Tweet'])

Train_X_Tfidf = Tfidf_vect.transform(Train_X)
Test_X_Tfidf = Tfidf_vect.transform(Test_X)

Train_X_Tfidf.shape
Train_Y.shape

SVM = SVC()
SVM.fit(Train_X_Tfidf, Train_Y)

predictions_SVM = SVM.predict(Test_X_Tfidf)

print("SVM Accuracy = ", accuracy_score(predictions_SVM, Test_Y)*100)
print("SVM Recall = ", recall_score(predictions_SVM, Test_Y)*100)
print("SVM Precision = ", precision_score(predictions_SVM, Test_Y)*100)
print("SVM f1 = ", f1_score(predictions_SVM, Test_Y)*100)
```